# Git stops resolving files as renamed after certain number of added/deleted files is reached

Tags: git, move

I have big ant project versioned in Git. We are currently changing building tool to maven. It means move all java source files into different directory structure. I created bash script to move java sources into one directory tree and other resources to another dir. tree. I'm converting one module (source code set) after another.

I run `git status` after moving each module and at first i see right status `RENAMED` with each file.

After i move another module and number of moved files reach **about 100**, git stops recognizing moved files and decouples them. That means that after running `git status` i see each file (event those recognized correctly before) twice. One `DELETED` in old path and one `NEW FILE` in new path.

Is there something that limits amount of files automatically resolved as renamed?

Comment: Do you move the files via "mv" or "git mv"? I have no idea if that makes a difference, but I'm interested in the solution myself ;)

Comment: git mv also stages the changes. There is no other difference according to git book http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository#Moving-Files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is your value of

```
diff.renameLimit
```

?

Try to set

```
git config diff.renameLimit 0
```

to disable the limit or try to set a very high value.

Comment: I haven't it in my configuration. If i set this option to 0 it didn't help. I also tried value 100000 but it didn't work either.

Comment: YOUR ANSWER IS RIGHT. Please add information, that `git status` shows bad (`deleted` and `new file`) information, but `git commit` renames the nodes right way. Thanks for your response. ||| in addition in this article http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Re-Intensive-rename-detection-td1452403.html Linus writes, that new versions of git can handle any number of "exact renames".. and realy, those files that was not properly renamed before have in commit messege not complete percentage(i.e. 97%) i don't know why.. it was just mv of file.. doesn't matter have commit. thanks again

Comment: Note that, for me, `git config diff.renameLimit 0` also fixed the output of `git status`